# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser nedded in clickonce

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I want to make a click once via `ftp`, after deploying the project and excute I have `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser V 10.0 needed .`

I have installed `1033\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi Version 10.50.2500.0`

but I can't found this file in the sdk directory ! and the other thing that I don't use this dll in my sollution !

How can I resolve this?Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably a dll that you use in your projects needs it and it is using it from the GAC. In your deployment machine there is no such dll. Open your project properties and click on "Publish". Click on "Application Files" button, and check "Show All Files" in the opened dialog. See if the missing dll is there and change its publish status to "Include".

Comment: Required means that the application won't open if it is missing. Is it included or excluded?

Comment: yes I know but I have installed SharedManagementObjects but the file missing until Now !